# Retrieve Data from Firebase Firestore and Bind to a MDLabel

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, kivy, kivymd, data-retrieval

I am building a `KivyMD` application and when the user enters the `Admission No`, I need to write a program to bind the data in the relevant document to an `MDLabel`. The `MDLabel` should be in the following format.

```
Name : name
Admission No : 75
Phone No : 726464783
```

**Database**

[Example Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFbWS.png)

**.kv**

```
MDFloatLayout:
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .55}
    TextInput:
        hint_text: "Admission No"
        id: ad_no
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'magnify'
        on_release:
            app.search_st()
    MDLabel:
        text: " "
        id : replace
```

**.py**

```
def search_st(self):
    import firebase_admin
    from firebase_admin import credentials
    from firebase_admin import firestore

    cred = credentials.Certificate("cred.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    self.db = firestore.client()
    ad_no = self.root.get_screen('search_st').ids.ad_no.text

    doc_ref = self.db.collection(u'Users').where(ad_no)

    doc = doc_ref.get()
    data = f'Document data: {doc.to_dict()}'
    if doc.exists:
        print(data)
        self.root.get_screen('search_st').ids.replaced.text = data
    else:
        print(u'No such document!')
```

The program I have written is not working properly. There are so many issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document), you can retrieve data from this method.

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'SF')

doc = doc_ref.get()
if doc.exists:
    print(f'Document data: {doc.to_dict()}')
else:
    print(u'No such document!')
```

In your case you should give the `ID` of the document you want to retrieve data.

**Example** :

```
002 - user 2
```

**I suggest you to try this Code.**

**.kv**

```
MDFloatLayout:
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .55}
    TextInput:
        hint_text: "Name"
        id: name
    TextInput:
        hint_text: "Admission No"
        id: ad_no
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'magnify'
        on_release:
            app.search_st()
    MDLabel:
        text: " "
        id : name_replaced
    MDLabel:
        text: " "
        id : ad_no_replaced
    MDLabel:
        text: " "
        id : phone_replaced
```

**.py**

```
def search_st(self):
    name = self.root.get_screen('search_st').ids.name.text
    ad_no = self.root.get_screen('search_st').ids.ad_no.text

    doc_name = ad_no + " - " + name

    doc_ref = self.db.collection(u'Users').document(doc_name)

    doc = doc_ref.get()

    if doc.exists:
        Name = str(doc.to_dict()['Name'])
        Admission_No = str(doc.to_dict()['Admission_No'])
        Phone_Number = str(doc.to_dict()['Phone_Number'])

        self.root.get_screen('search_st').ids.name_replaced.text = Name
        self.root.get_screen('search_st').ids.ad_no_replaced.text = Admission_Number
        self.root.get_screen('search_st').ids.phone_replaced.text = Phone_Number

    else:
        print('No such document!')
```